# Aptana adds new lines after saving

Tags: line, aptana

I have an issue that seemed to appear suddenly.

I am using Aptana Studio on Windows 7. After saving a file, and if I close Aptana and re-open it, a blank line is added between each line of my code.

For example:

```
$bError=FALSE;
$sReturnMsg='';
$sReturnType='';
```

which would then become:

```
$bError=FALSE;

$sReturnMsg='';

$sReturnType='';
```

Anyone would have an idea what is causing this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is an option in `Preferences > Aptana Studio > Editors > Remove trailing whitespace characters`. Have you tried changing this?

Comment: thanks I will try this. This is really weird. sometimes some whole pieces of code are also saved on one line, making the code to crash (and the code looks fine in aptana, I had to open it in another editor to notice the issue)